# how to run touch screen applications in non touch environment?

Tags: html, mobile, touch

I need to run the touch based browser app in my desktop and modify some codes written in touch events. Can some one tell me what are the best ways to run the touch screen apps in non touch environment? and check its event?

Comment: desktop app, or in-browser app?

Comment: browser app. code written in javascript and jquery

Comment: Run, or test? Just support click events everywhere.

Answer (score 1):

If your app is running inside a browser, you can emulate touch events on non-touch systems by turning on touch emulation in Chrome's developer tools.

In Chrome 26+ this can be found by clicking the "gear wheel" icon in the bottom right, and then selecting the "Overrides" panel.  See https://developers.google.com/chrome-developer-tools/docs/mobile-emulation#emulate-touch-events

NB: this will only work while the DevTools are open.  So it should be fine for testing, but not for end-user running.